# Operator norm of $T: L^{p}(0,\infty) \rightarrow L^{p}(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I hope you can help me with this exercise.

Let $p\in (1,\infty)$. Also,

\begin{align*}
T: L^{p}(0,\infty) &\rightarrow L^{p}(0,\infty)\\
f&\rightarrow (Tf)(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} f(y)\, dy
\end{align*}

(1) Show that $T$ is well defined and is continuous.

(2) $\|T\|=\dfrac{p}{p-1}.$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $T$ is well defined if $(Tf)(x)\in L^{p}(0,\infty)$? If so, i don't see it clearly. Also the number (2) is driving me nuts :(

Comment: Hints: Tonelli's (Fubini's for positive functions) and Hölder's will help solve the problem.

Comment: This is the famous Hardy's inequality. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality